# How to take related post MySql?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

i m trying to get related post based on tag

for example i have table like this

```
------------------------
post_id  |  term_id   |
-----------------------
   11    |     3      | 
   11    |     7      | 
   11    |     9      | 
   14    |     9      |
   14    |     1      |
   15    |     2      | 
   16    |     3      |
   16    |     4      | 
   16    |     8      | 
   16    |     2      | 
   18    |     3      | 
   18    |     4      | 
   18    |     5      |
   19    |     4      | 
   19    |     7      | 
...etc.,,
-----------------------
```

in the above table post_id 11 has 3 term_id 3,7,9 so now i need to check the same table and select other post which has same term_id.. post_id 16 , 18 has term_id 3 , and then post_id 19 has 7 term_id but term_id 9 not matched so i have to show another column as related posts id 16,18,19
something like this

post id 14 has term id 9 & 1 but no other post has 9 and 1 so this post dont have any related posts

```
------------------------------------------
post_id  |  term_id    |  related_post_id |
------------------------------------------
   11    |  3,7,9      |  16,18,19
   14    |  9,1        |  null
   15    |  2          |  16
   16    |  3,4,8,2    |  11,15,18,19
   18    |  3,4,5      |  11,16,19
   19    |  4,7        |  11,16,18
...etc.,,
------------------------
```

please some one help to solve this task.

Comment: Have you made any attempt yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok.. you can use this group_concat function... but there is an 1024 byte limit on size.. this will work.  Otherwise.. you are looking at a complex SQL in an SP to build the answer

```
select 
    tmp1.post_id, 
    myterm_id_list, 
    group_concat(distinct t2.post_id separator  ',') from

 (SELECT 
    distinct t1.post_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct t1.term_id SEPARATOR ',') as myterm_id_list
  FROM  test.tablename t1 
  left join test.tablename t2  on
      t2.post_id= t1.post_id
  GROUP BY t1.post_id
 ) as tmp1

 left join test.tablename t2 on
    t2.term_id in (tmp1.myterm_id_list)
 group by 
    tmp1.post_id,
    myterm_id_list
```